# How to use "." as a wildcard inside "string" instead of pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I have this:

```
incompleted_string1 = "Thom"
incompleted_string2 = "s Mueller naive"
entire_string = 'Thom.s Mueller naive'  # <= dot means any char!!! I dont know which char is it
pattern = "mas M"
```

I would like to know if "mas M" if present inside entire_string. I do not care if `"."` is equal to "a" or something else. I cannot change the pattern string!

```
re.findall("mas M", entire_string)
```

This returns `[]` I'd like to have `"mas M"` but `True` will be enough

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can't you simply look for `m.s M`?

Comment: `bool(re.search("".join([f"[{x}.]" for x in pattern]), entire_string))` ([demo](https://ideone.com/cYGKYp))

Comment: entire_string is equal to "Thom" + "UNKOWN" + "Mueller naive"

Comment: @miciobauciao is it safe to assume that the missing character is an ASCII character? or can it be *any* Unicode character?

Comment: Why don't you have the relevant part of the string as a pattern? `re.search('m.s M', 'mas M')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew maybe post that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

You can replace each char in the `pattern` with `[` + this char + `.` + `]`:

```
bool(re.search("".join([f"[{x}.]" for x in pattern]), entire_string))
```

The pattern will look like `[m.][a.][s.][ .][M.]` here, and each can match either the corresponding letter or a dot. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z8rG4Y/2/).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/cYGKYp):

```
import re
incompleted_string1 = "Thom"
incompleted_string2 = "s Mueller naive"
entire_string = 'Thom.s Mueller naive'  # <= dot means any char!!! I dont know which char is it
pattern = "mas M"
print (bool(re.search("".join([f"[{x}.]" for x in pattern]), entire_string)) )
# => True
```

Answer (score 1):

The another approach could be to have all the possible combinations of pattern

```
bool(re.search(pattern  + "|"+ "|".join([pattern[0:i] + '.' + pattern[i+1:] for i in range(len(pattern))]), entire_string))
```